# problems displaying JSON Data with Angular Js ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-controller

I am able to retrieve following JSON data (test data) from a php file :

**JSON:**

```
[{"id":"1","name":"shabri","desc":"bbkbjkbjbjnnklnln","location":"location","mobile":"498534534","telephone":"4549385","offer":"20","email":"nfnkjrnfnrndnrgnkjr"},{"id":"2","name":"bhagatfergdfgfdg","desc":"vfdgfdbgbbgbg","location":"fbgbgfbgfb","mobile":"544656757","telephone":"4223424","offer":"30","email":"vdsxdvgvgv"},{"id":"3","name":"rddfdgdf","desc":"bdffgd","location":"fghgfhfhgf","mobile":"8598","telephone":"856845","offer":"6","email":"httrdh6kiki"}]
```

**Angular Js Controller**

```
.controller('RestaurantsCtrl',  ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://xyz/getRestros.php')


.success(function(data) {
  alert(data);
  $scope.Restaurants = data;
  });
}])
```

I am sure that JSON data is retrieved because for testing i have alert(data) which displays correct json encoded data in the alert box.

**Issue is that data is not getting assigned to $scope.Restaurants. so ng-repeat in html is not populating the list.**

ng-repeat populates the list if i hard code $scope.Restaurants.

what's the mistake here ? please help..

**EDIT:**

hard coded $scope.Restaurants that works:

```
$scope.Restaurants = [
{ name: 'Shabri', id: 1 },
{ name: 'Bhagat Tarachand', id: 2 },
{ name: 'Udipi', id: 3 },
{ name: 'Shahu', id: 4 },
{ name: 'Bagdadi', id: 5 },
{ name: 'Shiv Sagar', id: 6 }
```

];

**ng-repeat:**

```
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="Restaurant in Restaurants | filter: searchText" href="#/app/Restaurants/{{Restaurant.id}}">
  <img src="img/default_restro.png" style="margin-top:30px;"/>
  <h2 style="font-weight:bold;">{{Restaurant.id}}</h2>
  <p>{{Restaurant.name}}</p><br>
  <span style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-weight:300;">This is the description about the restaurant click to know more.</span><br>


</a>
```

Comment: Please post your code, your repeater code might not be correct (a jsfiddle would be helpful). Also, you can add above your repeater:
<div> {{Restaurants}}</div> and see the json.

Comment: @Meir I didnt post my repeater because the same repeater works with hard coded $scope.Restaurants. which is of exact same format as json. Still i will post the repeater above and the hard coded $scope.Restaurant too that works.

Comment: @Meir i posted my ng-repeat , please check it

Comment: I will gladly. Before that, is it a string or an object (see the comment below on JSON.parse) + did you add a div to see the new content gets there?

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here, did you try %$scope.$apply() after the assignment?

Comment: Thanks for your time @meir . I got the solution , i posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do debugging in Chrome Developer Tools view (Ctrl-Shift-I) and set breakpoint to see if $scope.Restaurant has value assigned after the line 
    $scope.Restaurants = data;

Comment: thanks for the lead ! i just did that ! $scope.Restaurants has the values as expected. does this mean its something wrong with ng-repeat ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the returned JSON string into an object.

Try

```
arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
$scope.Restaurants = arrayData;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a answer but i found the root cause of the problem above and might happen with someone.

The free web hosting I was using to host that php file was the culprit.

Everytime that php is executed that web hosting appended some google analytics script at the end after the object ends. That script doesn't appear while live editing that file . i don't know how.

Anyway , i found it when i debugged the $scope.Restaurants again.

It seems that if anything else is echoed with the JSON object thn it would serialize and consider it string.

After correcting and changing the host , difference was spotted and it was considered as actual json objects, and it worked fine.